# my connection string doesn't work if I deploy my program to a different machine

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have a c# application that works locally but it wont work if I publish my program on another machine.  I get an error saying the server name cannot be found.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in ProductionOrderQuery.exe
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

Both machines are on the same corporate domain network.  it may be something to do with how I am specifying my server name?  Do I have to simply write the server name or do i need the fully qualified domain name?

The connection string is

```
Server=hostname\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

I'm using SS auth with sa account.

Do I need to do anything on SSMS to get this to work?

Edit: So I've since followed guides on how to connect by IP Address to see if it was DNS screwing it up.  I have configured named pipes and static ports and changed my connection string.  Firewall is disabled  Still can't connect remotely, everything works ok locally.  I did manage to get one machine to connect remotely and that's it, very puzzling.

New connection string is Data Source =

`<ip>,1433; Network Library = DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog = footfall; User ID = sa; Password=password;connection timeout=0;`

I can ping the server from the machine I'm trying to connect from and nslookup reports correct hostname.  I can run a trace from client to server fine.  Firewall is disabled on server for testing.

Edit 2: When somebody signs in to a remote machine that isn't me, they cant connect.  SO it seems there is still some kind of windows authentication going on here despite me specifically using the SA account.  When I sign in, I can connect ok.

SOLUTION: Bit of a wild goose chase here but turns out I had used a data source wizard to populate a combobox in design view that was using a different connection string.

You cant just remove datasources either from VS which is very annoying. Took me a while to remove them.

I don't understand why though if the data sources are not bound to anything on the form, the app still insists on connecting to them at runtime.

Once I managed to remove the data sources, and not use the SA account (I created a new account with read write perms on my database) the application worked.

I dont understand why I cant add the sa account to my database (receive an error when I do so) but a custom account I can add fine.

So to summarise, in the end there were 2 issues, the fact I was using the SA account and the hidden connection string in one of the data sources linked to the combo box

Thanks.

Comment: Remote connections need to be enabled in your database if they're not.

Comment: Thanks, yes they are enabled

Comment: have you tried doing username / pass authentication? THere are many ways to authenticate remotely.

Comment: Did u disable the firewall on the engine you want to connect? When you successfully connect to the machine are you local?

Comment: firewall disabled on server machine yea.  I can connect if I log in as me both locally and remotely but not as another user on the domain.

Comment: what is exact error message? which network protocol are you using? did you try to use TCP/IP protocol?

Comment: @Anton: I have added an exact error message above.  Yes I did try TCP/IP see other replies below.  tried connecting locally and remotely using windows auth and IP address using SA account.  It works for me but not any other domain user.

Comment: @DavidFolksman, when you connect the server using SQL and then windows authentication, can you check the connections and post the screenshots while you're connected SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections ? Did you check Event Viewer security logs for Failure Audit events (on the server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a wild goose chase here but turns out I had used a data source wizard to populate a combobox in design view that was using a different connection string.

You cant just remove datasources either from VS which is very annoying. Took me a while to remove them.

I dont understand why though if the data sources are not bound to anything on the form, the app still insists on connecting to them at runtime.

Once I managed to remove the data sources, and not use the SA account (I created a new account with read write perms on my database) the application worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please check "SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)" service on second machine it should be started.

You can type services.msc in run window and find "SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)" service name and just make sure it is started.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pWcm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the SQL Server Management Studio and click connect button to connect with database engine. After that copy server name and past it to place of server name in the connection string.

follow the image

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Ive done this and no joy im afraid.  I followed a few guides and ive been to connectoinstring.com.  Might be a firewall issue on my machine?

Comment: Great!! Did you change server name in connection string or It was ok? Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Yes, ive used hostname, ive used IP address with default and static ports.  Checked services are running (SQL Server and SERVER BROWSER are running but SQL Agent Services is Stopped and will not start.)  Named pipes is enabled and configured correctly.

Comment: @DavidFolksman, Is it working fine right now after done all the above things?

Comment: No, I can connect locally and remotely as me but not as any other domain user.

Answer (score 0):

lets take your server name:

```
DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS
```

then you can avoid your machine name in connection string like this.

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Thank You!

Comment: But what if im not connecting locally.  I want to connect remotely across a corporate domain as any domain user?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

Confirm that server authentication is in mixed mode, like in image bellow.

[image]

Confirm that sql server is allowing for remote connections:

[image]

Confirm that sa user is in your database users list and/or is associated with your database dbo role. Just in case, also try to check if sa is db_owner for that database.

I would continue using a default connection string:

data source=server\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=db;integrated security=false;user id=user;password=pwd;**Persist Security Info=True;**

The persist security is an important part when using user/password to authenticate.

Another thing is that in your question you are adding 2 slashes to the SQLEXPRESS instance, when it actually is just one.

Comment: Thanks ill try this.  I add 2 slashes to the instance as the first slash is an escape character for a c# string.  If I am using windows authentication as you specify in your connection string above, do I need to do anything on the server side to add specific user accounts as being able to connect to the database as this is not desired.  I just want any domain user to be able to use the application.

Comment: how do i check -> Confirm that sa user is in your database users list and/or is associated with your database dbo role. Just in case, also try to check if sa is db_owner for that database.

Comment: David, in the connection string you don't have to use 2 slashes. This can be one of your problems. When using windows auth, then every user that is running your app must be a user with access to your db. In this case you can use different roles for these users, like datareader/datawriter only.

Comment: This is why i was using the sa account and hard coding the username password into the connection string.  its not practical for me to have to add every user.   When you say "then every user that is running your app must be a user with access to your db. In this case you can use different roles for these users" how do i practically go about accomplishing this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue sometime. This is what worked for me:

Check the settings in the SQL Server Configuration Manager

> "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
>
> Click on "SQL Server Network Configuration" and Click on
>   "Protocols for Name"
>
> Right Click on "TCP/IP" (should be Enabled). Click on Properties
>
> On "IP Addresses" Tab go to the last entry "IP All"
>
> Enter "TCP Port" 1433.
>
> Now Restart "SQL Server .Name." using "services.msc" (winKey + r)

Comment: I have already done this "I have configured named pipes and static ports and changed my connection string".  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you also checked if the firewall is blocking the port 1433.

Comment: Ive disabled the firewall completely

Comment: The app works if I am logged in as me on any domain PC

Comment: But not as another user, thats why I tried using the SA account but it seems to be still using windows authentication some how

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a Firewall Issue. Disable any **antivirus**  or firewall installed in the second machine and check out if you are able to connect.

Comment: No, it isnt sorry.  Please see the rest of the replies and the op states firewall is disabled.